# Let $U, V \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be open sets and $f: U \to V$ a smooth map. Show that $f$ is holomorphic $\iff$ $df$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

> Let $U, V \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be open sets and $f: U \to V$ a smooth map. Show that $f$ is holomorphic $\iff$ $df$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

So if we assume first that $f$ is holomorphic, then $$df= \sum_{j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j} dz_j + \sum_{j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}_j} d\bar{z}_j = \sum_{j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j} dz_j $$ as $\bar{\partial} f = 0$. Now I'm not sure how to argue that this sum is $\mathbb{C}$-linear. Do I need to consider $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}$ or only $dz_j$ to conclude?

Comment: And to show that $dz_j$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear we need to show that for any $v \in T_xM$, $(dz_j)_x(c \cdot v) = c \cdot (dz_j)_x(v)$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$? @AnneBauval

Comment: Sorry I meant to write $v \in T_x \mathbb{C}^n$. Also I think that $dz_j := dx_j + idy_j$, but is this the same as the projection? @AnneBauval

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure of all my comments. I prefer to delete them.

Comment: If $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the standard basis on $\Bbb C^n$, then $z_1,\dots,z_n$ are the standard coordinates and $dz_1,\dots,dz_n$ is the dual basis. So if $v\in T_xU$, then $v=\sum v_je_j$ and $dz_j(v) = v_j$. By most people's conventions, $d\bar z_j(v) = \overline{dz_j(v)} = \bar v_j$. When you write $dz_j$ and $d\bar z_j$, this is the usual basis for the *complexified* cotangent bundle $T^*_xU\otimes C = T^{(1,0}U \oplus T^{(0,1)}U$. This requires more discussion than fits in a comment and you can find plenty of posts on this on the site.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a rephrasing of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and I think it is best understood using *real* coordinates. Consider $U$ and $V$ as smooth manifolds equipped with a complex structure $J$, given by multiplication by $i$ on the tangent spaces. So, if $f$ is a function between $U$ and $V$ and we have a tangent vector $v\in TU$ and a complex number $\lambda=\alpha+i\,\beta$. We want to understand when it is true that $\mathrm{d}f(\lambda\, v)=\lambda\,\mathrm{d}f(v)$. But the differential of $f$ is always $\mathbb{R}$-linear, so $$\mathrm{d}f(\lambda\, v)=\lambda\,\mathrm{d}f(v)\iff \mathrm{d}f(J\,v)=J(\mathrm{d}f(v)).$$ So we want to understand when the differential of $f$ commutes with the complex structure $J$.

Let $(z^1,\dots,z^n)$ be the standard complex coordinates, and set $z^a=x^a+i\,y^a$. Then $\mathrm{d}z^a=\mathrm{d}x^a+i\,\mathrm{d}y^a$, and
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_{z^a}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{x^a}-i\,\partial_{y^a}\right)\\
\partial_{\bar{z}^a}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{x^a}+i\,\partial_{y^a}\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So a function $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $\partial_{x^a}f=-i\,\partial_{y^a}f$.

Now, the differential of $f$ in local coordinates is $$\mathrm{d}f=\partial_{x_a}f\,\mathrm{d}x^a+\partial_{x_a}f\,\mathrm{d}x^a$$

letting $f=u+i\,v$, this is equivalent to the function $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\mapsto(u(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}),v(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}))$ having a Jacobian of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ -B & A
\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, the complex structure in the local coordinate system $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ is instead written as $J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\mathrm{Id}_{n\times n} \\ \mathrm{Id}_{n\times n} & 0\end{pmatrix}$, and a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} X & Y \\ W & Z \end{pmatrix}$ commutes with $Z$ if and only if
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\mathrm{Id}_{n\times n} \\ \mathrm{Id}_{n\times n} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} X & Y \\ W & Z \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} X & Y \\ W & Z \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\mathrm{Id}_{n\times n} \\ \mathrm{Id}_{n\times n} & 0\end{pmatrix}=0,$$ which is to say $W=-Y$ and $X=Z$. So, $f$ is holomorphic if and only if its Jacobian commutes with the complex structure. To finish the proof you just need to notice that $\mathrm{d}f$ is represented in a system of local coordinates exactly by the Jacobian of $f$.

Depending on your taste, this might just be a very complicated explanation for a simple property, but honestly I think that these kind of questions are much more clear when using real coordinates rather than complex ones.